# Question about compile-time-errors

Tags: perl, compilation

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;

say "no semicolon"

say "World";
say "World";
say "World";
say "World";
say "World";

# syntax error at ./perl1.pl line 7, near "say"
# Execution of ./perl1.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;

my $character = "\x{ffff}";

say "Hello";
say "Hello";
say "Hello";
say "Hello";
say "Hello";

# Unicode non-character 0xffff is illegal for interchange at ./perl1.pl line 5.
# Hello
# Hello
# Hello
# Hello
# Hello
```

Why doesn't the second script tell me, that there was a compile-time-error?

When I can't - with a "use warnings FATAL => qw(all);" - catch the error with Try::Tiny or block-eval, can I conclude, that it is a compile-time-error?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings FATAL => qw(all);
use 5.012;
use Try::Tiny;

my $character;

try {
    $character = "\x{ffff}";
} catch {
    die "---------- caught error ----------\n";
};

say "something";

# Unicode non-character 0xffff is illegal for interchange at ./perl1.pl line 9.
```

Comment: The program executed, so there can be no compile-time error in the program... If there was a compile-time error, the program would not be able to run.

Comment: If I would ask: "..., can I conclude, that it is no run-time-error and no run-time-warning", would that be OK?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Unicode non-character 0xffff is illegal for interchange at ...` is a compile time warning.

When you `use warnings FATAL => all`, you are asking Perl to treat all warnings as errors, hence it becomes a compile time error.